# Why did the latitude results object change from the google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I am hitting the google maps api while passing in a city like so:

```
this.geoCode = function(city) {
        var dfd = $q.defer();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({'address': city},
            function (results, status) {
                console.log('map response: ', results);
                cityObj.address = results[0].formatted_address;
                getWeather(results[0].geometry.bounds.R.R, results[0].geometry.bounds.j.j)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        cityObj = response;
                        dfd.resolve(cityObj);
                    });
            });
            return dfd.promise;
    };
```

Just 2 weeks ago I was accessing the latitude/longitude from the results object by:

```
getWeather(results[0].geometry.bounds.R.R, results[0].geometry.bounds.j.j)
```

Now the results object looks like this:

```
getWeather(results[0].geometry.bounds.H.H, results[0].geometry.bounds.j.j)
```

as you can see, the latitude went from being accessed on the R.R object to being accessed on the H.H object.  I don't know if this is something googlemaps frequently does.  If it is, how could use the code to continually parse through the data to get the latitude/longitude without continually changing the object letters?  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: You can access lat, lng using this, this is working fine for me.

var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

Comment: duplicate of [Google Maps API V3 - only showing a blank map when using the geocoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114797/google-maps-api-v3-only-showing-a-blank-map-when-using-the-geocoder)

Comment: duplicate of [Google maps - Weird geometry.location attributes (G, K)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614504/google-maps-weird-geometry-location-attributes-g-k)

Comment: duplicate of [Google map does not show up using Geocode services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927901/google-map-does-not-show-up-using-geocode-services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to it being minified, the property names aren't always named the same and aren't meant to be accessed directly.

[geometry.bounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResults) is a [LatLngBounds instance](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds). As such you use the methods like `getCenter()` to get a [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object which you can then get the latitude and longitude values

```
var center = results[0].geometry.bounds.getCenter();
var lat = center.lat();
var lng = center.lng();
```

Or you can also use `geometry.location` as it is already a usable `LatLng` instance, it all depends on which coordinates you are needing to retrieve.